# Calculating resistance for metal layer from LEF File

Tags: semiconductors, vlsi, asic, electrical, physical-design

I have a .LEF File which has various metals description and their parasitics information. I am trying to calculate R. It is specified as  RPERSQ = 0.278. 
In the File description it is written as Units of Resistance is Ohms and also resistancePrecision       = 1000000.
I think that RPERSQ = 0.278 is not ohms and it has something to calculate with the resistancePrecision.
Can anyone please help me on this.

Thanks,
Ramu

Answer (score 1):

RESPSQ is resistance per square. It is common to describe sheet resistance as ohms/square or \$ \cfrac{\Omega}{\Box}\$ as the size of the square does not matter.

You can find more about it here: [Sheet Resistance wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheet_resistance)

Comment: Thank you for your reference, But do we need to take into consideration the resistancePrecision. I couldn't get what that term is actually